# Unable to Collapse Navigation in Bootstrap 3 Website on iPad

Tags: css, navigation, nav

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to collapse the navigation of my Bootstrap 3 website on my iPad. The website is [allisonbrandonwexler.com.](http://allisonbrandonwexler.com)

Based on some research, I figured this is the code that needs changed in my theme's .css file, but nothing I do works:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-custom {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
    padding: 0;
    background: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }
}
```

And honestly, although the navigation collapses on my iPhone X in landscape mode as I want it to, I'm not even sure why that works given the pixel width of the iPhone X (when in landscape) is obviously more than 768px.

My site's CSS file can be found here: https://github.com/brandonwexler/brandonwexler.github.io/tree/master/css

...and the bootstrap.css file can be found here: https://github.com/brandonwexler/brandonwexler.github.io/tree/master/vendor/bootstrap/css

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Please include relevant code in the body of the question, not as off-site links that may change, go stale, or just need someone to make multiple clicks to read.

Comment: Hey @Dragonthoughts, I appreciate the comment, but the problem is I don’t know what code might be relevant outside of what I included in the post, and I obviously don’t want to copy entire style sheets in the post that are 3000+ lines long. If there’s a better way to communicate this, though, I’m all ears!